# Finding variable text between two constants with Applescript

Tags: javascript, string, applescript, html

I am new to applescript. I am trying to return a string to a variable from a web page via safari. The target string changes, but the words preceding and following are static.

example: Apple 1293.34 USD

the "Apple " and " USD" never change, but all i want is the number in between.

The element does not have an ID and I have not had luck trying to get by class with Javascript.

thanks :)

Comment: If you can it is always a good idea when asking these sort of questions to put in a link to the site you are referring to.

Comment: i hope someone figurse this out

Answer (score 0):

You should first find your element.

```
var element = document.getElementById("elementID");
```

Then get your value:

```
 var value = parseFloat(element.innerText.split(" ")[1])
```

Comment: The element doesn't have an ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse Curl...

```
set myUrl to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633200/finding-variable-text-between-two-constants-with-applescript"

set xxx to do shell script "curl " & quoted form of myUrl & " | grep -o Apple.*USD | sed 's/Apple\\(.*\\)USD/\\1/'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an applescript method given the text. This does not assume Apple is found only once in the text. This will look through and find where Apple is followed 2 words later by USD, and then get the proper value between them.

```
set theText to "USD some words Apple USD more words Apple 1293.34 USD some words Apple USD"

set {tids, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, "Apple"}
set textItems to text items of theText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tids

set theValue to missing value
repeat with i from 2 to (count of textItems)
    set thisItem to item i of textItems
    try
        if word 2 of thisItem is "USD" then
            set theValue to word 1 of thisItem
            exit repeat
        end if
    end try
end repeat

return theValue
```

Comment: Can you explain what is going on here ?

Comment: Basically the "text item" stuff at the beginning of the script turns theText string into a list. The list is broken up into components based on the word "Apple". Here's the list: {"USD some words ", " USD more words ", " 1293.34 USD some words ", " USD"}. Then I use the repeat loop to iterate over the list items. I know that if the second word of one of the list items is "USD" then I have found what I am looking for... and therefore I return the first word of that list item. You can see the third item is the one I want, and the first word of that item is "1293.34".